# Keyboard Extension Crash on Device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-keyboard-extension

maybe you can help me?

I've got a keyboard extension to work before on a device, but in my new project, it doesn't work... On the simulator, it works fine. I add the keyboard in Settings, and allow full access on both simulator and device.

On the device, when I switch from any other keyboard to the new keyboard, it pauses for a bit, like it is loading, and a Xcode error pops up: Lost connection to "Kjell Connelly’s iPhone". Restore the connection to "Kjell Connelly’s iPhone" and run "com.2xpop.KeyboardRPG.Keyboard-RPG" again, or if "com.2xpop.KeyboardRPG.Keyboard-RPG" is still running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > com.2xpop.KeyboardRPG.Keyboard-RPG.

Sometimes the popup happens right away when I switch to the new keyboard, but sometimes it happens after the keyboard tries to load for a few seconds.

I did what the popup says, and tried to attach the debugger to the process, but it never attaches.

I thought that maybe too much was happening in the app, so I commented out all of the code in the viewDidAppear and viewDidLoad methods (except the super parts) so at least the keyboard would appear blank. Still didn't help.

Anyone have this problem before or have any ideas?

The normal app works as expected, but just not the extension, and only on device.

Answer (score 1):

Oh jeez, i just figured it out, after a few weeks of putting this project off because being stuck: I need to have arm64 working... I turned it off because the current AdMob SDK doesn't work for arm64. But thats ok because the extension doesn't use ads, only the original app.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same problem, but it appears like I already have arm64 working. Just to be sure under Valid Architectures, I have the following: ```arm64, armv7, armv7s``` yet I still can't get the debugger to work. :/

Comment: @KingPolygon did you find a Solution I have the same Problem and I have all architectures like you