# Keyboard extension works in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-keyboard-extension

I am developing custom keyboard extension. It worked fine in both simulator and device until now.

After some small changes (adding `import AudioToolbox` in one class and one command) it suddenly stopped working on the device. The app compiles and runs but then I acivate my keyboard XCode shows following error:

```
Lost connection to "My iPhone".
Restore the connection to "My iPhone" and run "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-Keyboard" 
again, or if "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-Keyboard" is still running, you can 
attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-Keyboard.
```

This error looks like the one that appears when iPhone cable is unplagged but the cable is all right in this case.

My keyboard itself is not launched - when activated (using globe key) there is few seconds delay (which is normal when my keyboard is loading in debug) and then the previously active keyboard is shown.

There are month of development in that project and I am completely stack so any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: There is [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27305055/311865) unfortunatelly the cause is probably different in my case as i already have `amr64` among supported architectures (the answer there does not work in my case).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

- unplaged iPhone cable
- Cleared project
- Closed XCode, restarted computer
- built project and all linked libraries from scratch
- Restarted iPhone, deleted app containing keyboard extension, restarted iPhone
- reconnected iPhone cable, run extension

Answer (score 5):

For me the problem was that the app deployment target was different than the extension deployment target

Go to your Project settings and make sure the main target and the keyboard target share the same deployment target value under "General" tab.

Answer (score 0):

I found that simply restarting Xcode usually does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity: I was using a Beta version xcode, so the Keyboard target defaulted to 'Deployment Target 11.0'. My device was on 10.3, so the installation was silently failing.

I fixed by setting the deployment target to an older OS version (8.0 in this case) as @yogev132 suggested.

I also had to kill and restart the 'Settings' app, to see my keyboard in the 'Add Keyboards' menu.